# scrollIntoView without jumping to top

Tags: javascript

I'm using scrollIntoView() for a thumbnail carousel, so when clicking on the thumbnail image the matching main image is scrolled into view.

```
if (itemEl.dataset.index === feature.dataset.index) {
  feature.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', inline: 'start' })
}
```

This works fine, the only issue I've got with it is I only really want it to scroll on the x-axis so horizontally, not vertically. I know there's the `block` option but none of the values for that stop the page from jumping vertically in my case so I was wondering if there's any way to get rid of the vertical scroll?

Comment: Since you want custom scrolling behavior that can't be provided by `scrollIntoView`, you'll have to do it custom. Use CSS to make the container animate changes to its horizontal scroll position, and then use JS to change the horizontal scroll position. (You could do it with pure JS, but using CSS is more resilient against runtime performance bottlenecks.)